# Go обработка Post запроса на сервере

Tags: сервер, http, golang

Добрый день. Есть маленький http handler. 
package main

```
func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello world!")
    fmt.Println("Zapros")
}
```

Через Advanced Rest Client(chrome) посылаю Post со строкой:

```
 { "name": "Вася", "age": 35, "isAdmin": false}
```

Как мне обработать/спарсить это содержимое в хендлере?

Answer (score 1):

Если ваши запросы будут однотипны в виде `json`, можно описать это структурой и записывать в нее запрос, в дальнейшем можно будет удобно работать:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

//структура описывающая запрос
type Foo struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Age     int    `json:"age"`
    IsAdmin bool   `json:"isAdmin"`
}

func requestHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var resp Foo

    //читаем тело запроса
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    //проверяем на наличие ошибки
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "err %q\n", err, err.Error())
    } else {
        //если все нормально - пишем по указателю в структуру
        err = json.Unmarshal(body, &resp)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(w, "can't unmarshal: ", err.Error())
        }
    }
    //выводим полученные данные (можно делать с данными все, что угодно)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Name:", resp.Name, "Age:", resp.Age, "IsAdmin:", resp.IsAdmin)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

где то так

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%q", b)        
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "ok")
} else {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "err %q\n", err)
}
```